# Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) - Is "CAN" relationship considered total participation?

Tags: data-structures, entity-relationship, erd

In Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) is the word usage **CAN** considered total participation or partial participation?

For example, given the statement: 
*"An apple CAN be eaten by many different students."*

In this relationship between the entities *apple* and *students*, would the *apple* considered to be in a total participation or partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no formal rule in the entity-relationship model about the word "CAN". It's up to the data modeler to name relationships and decide the cardinality and participation of the roles.

My common sense says that "CAN" implies partial participation, unless it's accompanied by "MUST". For example, if "An apple CAN be eaten by many different students", then it can also be eaten by no students. If the participation was total, I would expect a word like "MUST" or "SHALL", e.g. "An apple MUST be eaten by at least one student, and CAN be eaten by many different students".

In the case of one-to-one relationships, we can distinguish "An apple CAN be eaten by a student" vs "An apple MUST be eaten by a student". Again, "CAN" sounds like partial participation.